# When do representations of a group "act on" the "original" vector space?

Tags: representation-theory

I am very unfamiliar with representation theory, and so this question may be vague, but I am trying to get a sense of the various concepts in the field.

For example, consider the group of transformations which leave $x^2 + y^2$ invariant. We can **represent** this group with the set of $2 \times 2$ matrices:
$$\begin{pmatrix} \cos \theta & \sin \theta \\ -\sin \theta & \cos \theta \end{pmatrix}.$$

We can then "act" this representation on $x,y$:
$$\begin{pmatrix} \cos \theta & \sin \theta \\ -\sin \theta & \cos \theta \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} x' \\ y' \end{pmatrix}$$
And when we do this we very clearly see how $x^2 + y^2 = x'^2 + y'^2.$

However there is no need to think of these matrices as acting on the original $x,y.$ We could also represent this group as $5\times 5$ matrices, so long as the map is still a group homomorphism. Is there a name for when the representation we have chosen is "natural" in the preceding sense?

Secondly, what would be the interesting things we could say
about the new space of $5 \times 1$ column vectors on which the $5 \times 5$ matrices act? Will there be a homomorphism from these to the $2 \times 1$ column vectors in the preceding example?

When are the properties of the representation/matrices dependent on the choice of **representation** versus the **group**?

In Quantum Mechanics, for example, the property of "spin" seems to depend on the representation and not the group SO$(3,1)$. The group SO$(3,1)$ seems to "naturally" act on the $4 \times 1$ column vectors so that $t^2 - |\vec{x}|^2$ is an invariant, but to get spin we instead represent it as a subspace of SL$(2s +1, \mathbb{C})$.

Comment: Technically, your matrix group doesn’t include reflections, like $(x,y)\mapsto (x,-y),$ which also preserve $x^2+y^2.$ Your matrices are the maps which preserve $x^2+y^2$ and “orientation.”

Comment: There isn’t a sense in which representations are “natural,” but there is a sense in which they are decomposable. Given two representations $U,V$ oh can define a representation $U\oplus V.$ If a representation is isomorphic to any (non-trivial) sum of two representations, it is considered reducible. Otherwise, it is irreducible. Your representation is reducible, at least if considered as actions on $\mathbb C^2.$ (We usually deal with representations on vector spaces over algebraically closed fields, for easier analysis of matrices.)

Comment: However, if your group included reflections, so the matrices were:$$\begin{pmatrix}\cos x&\sin x\\\mp\sin x&\pm\cos x\end{pmatrix}$$ then this representation would be irreducible.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews If you would like to bundle these comments together as an answer then I could vote on it .  I believe that there are "faithful" and "fundamental" representations